# step function that increases gait with X

Tags: math

I feel like a moron for not seeing how to express this.

I have need of a step function that approximates a linear function, with frequent, small steps near 0 and fewer, larger steps as X grows, approach some nominal max gait.

e.g.

```
                      /  |
                     /   |
                    /____| +5
                   /|
                  / |
                 /  |
                /   |
               /____| +5
              /|
             / |
            /  |
           /   |
          /____| +5
         /|
        / |
       /  |
      /___| +4
     /|
    / |
   /__| +3
  /|
 /_| +2
/| +1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want a function whose graph is the horizontal lines in your example.

If you check the graph's corners that lie on the line, you see that the `x`-coordinates (as well as the `y`-coordinates) are the triangular numbers `0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...` They are the partial sums of the arithmetic series `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ...`

It is well known that the formula for the nth triangular number is

```
x = n*(n+1)/2
```

That is a quadratic equation in `n`. If we solve that equation for `n` and take the positive root we get

```
n = (-1 + sqrt(8*x + 1)) / 2
```

So given any point on one of your horizontal line segments, we can find which segment it is by taking the integer part (floor) of that expression. We then use our original expression to find the appropriate `y` value for that segment. Thus our final expression, slightly simplified, is

```
0.5 * int((-1 + sqrt(8*x + 1))/2) * int((1 + sqrt(8*x + 1))/2)
```

Note that the above expression is undefined for `x < -1/8` and is zero for `-1/8 <= x < 0`. To avoid those, only graph for `x >= 0`. That is an expression in one line. In a computer program there are some obvious efficiencies that could be made, such as calculating `n = int((-1 + sqrt(8*x + 1))/2)` before using the function value `0.5 * n * (n + 1)`. You could also avoid the negative `x` values.

Here is the resulting graph (unfortunately leaving in the values for `-1/8 <= x < 0`), with dashed vertical and diagonal lines added for clarity.[image]

Comment: This is great, and I feel less dumb for not getting it.

Comment: Also, in reality we have rise and run coefficients that I have to factor in.  The actual line might be `10 + (2/3)*x`

Comment: Oh, for more fun, the gait would ideally asymptotically approach some maximum, so e.g. after N steps it settles on a final step size.

Comment: @TimHockin: You would need to clarify those two points before I could give a modified expression. But you could handle your first point by using `10 + (2/3) * f(x)` where `f(x)` is the expression in my answer. You could handle the second point by using something like `min(n, N)` rather than `x` in my expression that was split into two parts.

Comment: I plotted that and it looks right.  I want to make 2 changes, though.  I want to use ceil() rather than floor(), because the application here is modelling resource usage per managed-unit, and there's a meaningful difference between 1 managed unit and 0 managed units.

The second part is hard to express.  The bigger X gets, the smaller the per-X increment should be, which converges on a "final" gait.  E.g. X>1024 results in a constant step function with the same slope.

Thanks for your help.  I feel like I am in high school math again. :)

Comment: I don't know how to fix the remaining issues ;)  Changing floor() to ceil() drifts of the main line I need to track.